# How to show the last value of the another table column based on the between date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables:

- INVOICE, contains the entry date
- INVOICE_ITEM contains the product cod's
- PRODUCTS, here contains the STANDARD column, if i use the Nvl(P.STANDARD, 'Y'). It shows only the actual date value.
- PRODUCT_HIST (contains all the updates of the products table)

I'm trying to select the "standard" value of the product_hist based on the invoice entry date.

Here is my select, it works but doesnt show the correct value

```
SELECT NT.INVOICE
      , NT.PROVIDER
      , NT.ENTRY
      , NTI.PRODUCT
      , P.COD
      , P.NAME
      , Nvl(P.STANDARD, 'Y') "STANDARD_ACTUAL"
      , COALESCE (PRODUCT_HIST.STANDARD, P.PRODUCT, 'Y') "STANDARD2"
      FROM INVOICE NT
      INNER JOIN INVOICE_ITEM NTI ON NT.NOTE = NTI.NOTE AND NT.PROVIDER = NTI.PROVIDER
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.COD = NTI.PRODUCT
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT PH.COD COD
                 , Nvl(PH.STANDARD, Last_Value(PH.STANDARD IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY PH.COD ORDER BY PH.DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) STANDARD
                 , DATE
                 , Nvl(Lag(PH.DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PH.COD ORDER BY PH.DATE DESC), SYSDATE) FINALDATE
                 , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY COD ORDER BY COD, DATE, STANDARD DESC) ORDER
                 FROM PRODUCT_HIST PH) PRODUCT_HIST ON PRODUCT_HIST.COD = P.COD AND NT.ENTRY BETWEEN PRODUCT_HIST.DATE AND PRODUCT_HIST.FINALDATE AND PRODUCT_HIST.ORDER = 1
      
     WHERE NT.ENTRY BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')+0.99999
```

I need to show the last value of the "standard" between the entry invoice date, sometimes it will be null, so i have to use NVL or COALESCE.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment, but unformatted SQL statements are unreadable.

What is the issue with something like;

```
SELECT NT.INVOICE
      , NT.PROVIDER
      , NT.ENTRY
      , NTI.PRODUCT
      , P.COD
      , P.NAME
      , Nvl(P.STANDARD, 'Y') "STANDARD_ACTUAL"
      , COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(PH.STANDARD) FROM PRODUCT_HIST PH WHERE PH.COD = P.COD AND NT.ENTRY BETWEEN PRODUCT_HIST.DATE AND PRODUCT_HIST.FINALDATE AND PRODUCT_HIST.ORDER = 1),
                  P.PRODUCT, 'Y') "STANDARD2"
      FROM INVOICE NT
      INNER JOIN INVOICE_ITEM NTI ON NT.NOTE = NTI.NOTE AND NT.PROVIDER = NTI.PROVIDER
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.COD = NTI.PRODUCT
      LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_HIST PH ON PH.COD = P.COD AND 
     WHERE NT.ENTRY BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')+0.99999
```

Let me know how I missed the mark if it isn't close.

OK, this is a bit more convoluted, but it may work;

```
SELECT NT.INVOICE
      , NT.PROVIDER
      , NT.ENTRY
      , NTI.PRODUCT
      , P.COD
      , P.NAME
      , Nvl(P.STANDARD, 'Y') "STANDARD_ACTUAL"
      , COALESCE ((SELECT PH.STANDARD 
                   FROM PRODUCT_HIST PH 
                   WHERE PH.COD = P.COD AND 
                         NT.ENTRY BETWEEN PH.DATE AND 
                         PH.FINALDATE AND 
                         PH.ORDER = 1 AND 
                         PH.DATE = (SELECT MAX(PH1.DATE) 
                                    FROM PRODUCT_HIST PH1 
                                    WHERE PH1.COD = P.COD AND 
                                    NT.ENTRY BETWEEN PH1.DATE AND 
                                    PH1.FINALDATE AND 
                                    PH1.ORDER = 1) AND
                         ROWNUM = 1)
                         ),
                  P.PRODUCT, 'Y') "STANDARD2"
      FROM INVOICE NT
      INNER JOIN INVOICE_ITEM NTI ON NT.NOTE = NTI.NOTE AND NT.PROVIDER = NTI.PROVIDER
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.COD = NTI.PRODUCT
      LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_HIST PH ON PH.COD = P.COD AND 
     WHERE NT.ENTRY BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')+0.99999
```

Comment: Didn't work because PH.standard isn't a date but a value, i can't use MAX on it. Maybe something like that can work? SELECT PH.PADRAO FROM (SELECT Max(PH.DATAREAL) FROM PRODUTOS_HIST PH

Comment: MAX is available for all Oracle data types. Obviously I am missing something. Are you suggesting you need "STANDARD" from the row with the greatest NT.ENTRY within the range of PRODUCT_HIST.DATE AND PRODUCT_HIST.FINALDATE?

Comment: Yes, thats it. How can I do it?